# Google Cloud Speech Recognition Permission Denied Error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

I am trying to do Google cloud Speech Recognition for personal assistant built on python. I have a service account and also have setup GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_CREDENTIALS and also have enabled the API. But its not working. This is the example code from official page.

```
from google.cloud import speech
client = speech.SpeechClient()
results = client.recognize(
    audio=speech.types.RecognitionAudio(
        uri='gs://my-bucket/recording.flac',
    ),
    config=speech.types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding='LINEAR16',
        language_code='en-US',
        sample_rate_hertz=44100,
    ),
)
for result in results:
    for alternative in result.alternatives:
        print('=' * 20)
        print('transcript: ' + alternative.transcript)
        print('confidence: ' + str(alternative.confidence))
```

Error:

```
(base) C:\Users\mnauf>C:/Users/mnauf/Anaconda3/python.exe d:/Programming/python/mic.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mnauf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mnauf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 533, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "C:\Users\mnauf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 467, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED
        details = "The caller does not have permission"
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1543062997.122000000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1017,"grpc_message":"The caller
does not have permission","grpc_status":7}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Programming/python/mic.py", line 10, in <module>
    sample_rate_hertz=44100,
  File "C:\Users\mnauf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\speech_v1\gapic\speech_client.py", line 227, in recognize
    request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata)
  File "C:\Users\mnauf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\method.py", line 139, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mnauf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 260, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "C:\Users\mnauf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 177, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "C:\Users\mnauf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\timeout.py", line 206, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mnauf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 61, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 The caller does not have permission
```

Answer (score 1):

At the line `uri='gs://my-bucket/recording.flac',` change the path to your own bucket with the file you want to translate, as that bucket may indeed exist, since [bucket names are unique](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming#considerations) in GCP, and you therefore have no permission to access it with your service account key.